# Vaadin Grails: Can not process requests before init() has been called

Tags: grails, vaadin, grails-plugin, vaadin7

I'm trying to setup the Vaadin Grails plugin, but when following the instructions from [here](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Vaadin%20on%20Grails%20-%20Create%20project%20in%20IntelliJ%20IDEA) I run into the following error when actually running the app:

```
| Error 2014-03-05 14:03:14,922 [http-bio-8080-exec-5] ERROR [/ria-app].[VaadinServlet 0]  - Servlet.service() for servlet [VaadinServlet 0] in context with path [/ria-app] threw exception
Message: Can not process requests before init() has been called
    Line | Method
->> 1292 | requestStart  in com.vaadin.server.VaadinService
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1371 | handleRequest in     ''
|    238 | service . . . in com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet
|   1145 | runWorker     in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run           in java.lang.Thread
```

The full stack trace is available [here](http://cld.rnbk.org/text/3O3a341n0p2Y).

Comment: this comes most likely from 7.1.10.1. I reverted back to 7.1.10 and it was gone in my case.

Comment: @cfrick - You're right! Thanks for that. I wonder what the issue is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is fixed in 7.1.10.2 or if you want also update Vaadin version then 7.1.11.

Comment: Can you link to the bug just so I know what caused it? I'm quite curious.

Comment: @brennebeck https://github.com/ondrej-kvasnovsky/grails-vaadin-plugin/commit/745a5cd27eb300127766ca404f3267306592d6f9